# Strictly convex normed vector space

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, normed-spaces

I have a question about an exercise of Brezis Functional Analysis (Ex. 1.26).

Let $(X, \|\cdot \| )$ be a n.v.s. Now I have to prove that $\| \cdot \|$ is strictly convex iff $\phi(x)  := \| x \|^p$ is strictly convex for $p \in \ ]1,\infty[$.

My attempt so far:

- Let $\phi(x)$ be strictly convex. For $x,y \in X$ with $\|x\| = \| y \| = 1$, $\lambda \in ]0,1[$ we have:
  $$ \phi(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) = \|\lambda x + (1- \lambda )y \|^p  < \lambda \|x\|^p + (1-\lambda )\|y\|^p = 1  $$
  This proves that $ \| \cdot \| $ is strictly convex. Correct?

This seems like an obvious ex., but I still am confused, every hint is appreciated. Especially for the other direction.